# AttributeError on googletrans libary in Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I added my whole code and the error report.
https://paste.centos.org/view/863c4b41

Comment: please provide a [mre] in your post, not external links.

Comment: I agree with the above comment, please post your code here and don't link to an external site. Having a cursory glance at your link, are you forgetting parentheses on line 12?